# How to prove $(f \circ\ g) ^{-1} = g^{-1} \circ\ f^{-1}$? (inverse of composition)

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, inverse-function, function-and-relation-composition

I'm doing exercise on discrete mathematics and I'm stuck with question:

> If $f:Y\to Z$ is an invertible function, and $g:X\to Y$ is an invertible function, then the inverse of the composition $(f \circ\ g)$ is given by $(f \circ\ g) ^{-1} = g^{-1} \circ\ f^{-1}$.

I've no idea how to prove this, please help me by give me some reference or hint to its solution.

Comment: To prove that $F^{-1}$ is an inverse of a function $F$ you need to show that $F^{-1}\circ F(x)=x$ and also $F\circ F^{-1}(x)=x$

Comment: Please try to use more descriptive titles when asking questions.

Comment: @Akhil: could you suggest more descriptive title for this question please, I'm not very good in English.

Comment: @Pete: It's been edited since when I posted the comment.

Comment: @Akhil: It has had this title (except with "proof" instead of "prove") even before your comment. I think what happened is that when you saw the question on the main page, the math was not rendered immediately, and you saw "How to proof ?".

Comment: @ShreevatsaR: I think you're correct; actually, I had not set up the math rendering at that point, and assumed that the question was titled "How to proof." My apologies to idonno.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the definition of an inverse and associativity of composition to show that the right hand side is the inverse of $(f \circ g)$.

Comment: Right hand side mean both (f o g) -1 and g-1 o f-1 ?

Comment: I think the idea of Dylan is that if you call $h=f\circ g$ then we have that $h\circ (g^{-1} \circ f^{-1}) = (f\circ g) \circ (g^{-1} \circ f^{-1}) = Id$, using the associativity of composition, which shows that $g^{-1} \circ f^{-1}$ is the inverse of $h$.

Answer (score 42):

You put your socks first and then your shoes but you take off your shoes before taking off your socks.

Comment: While funny, I think this as a stand-alone comment, is not quite helpful. If you briefly showed how it was related however, I think it would be a very useful answer.

Comment: it's not just funny! Think of 'putting on socks' as 'applying the function f', taking them off as the inverse. and 'putting on shoes' as 'applying g'.

Comment: @muad: Yes, *we* understand, but for someone struggling to prove the statement in the title, the connection is probably not obvious.

Comment: This is amazingly clear intuitively, but it doesn't constitute a mathematical proof

Comment: for me, is not intuitive, because there are not conceptos of bijectivity for put a sock

Answer (score 15):

$$\begin{align}
& \text{id} \\\\
=& f \circ f^{-1} \\\\
=& f  \circ \text{id} \circ f^{-1} \\\\
=& f \circ (g \circ g^{-1}) \circ f^{-1} \\\\
=& f \circ g \circ g^{-1} \circ f^{-1} \\\\
=& (f \circ g) \circ (g^{-1} \circ f^{-1})
\end{align}$$

Therefore $(f \circ g)^{-1} = g^{-1} \circ f^{-1}$.

Answer (score 3):

$f:Y \to Z$ and $g:X \to Y$ are invertible functions. We need to prove $(f\circ g)^{-1}=g^{-1}\circ f^{-1}$.

$$
(f\circ g)^{-1}\circ (f\circ g)=(g^{-1}\circ f^{-1})\circ(f\circ g)=(g^{-1}\circ f^{-1})\circ f)\circ g=(g^{-1}\circ (f^{-1}\circ f))\circ g=(g^{-1}\circ I_{Y})\circ g=g^{-1}\circ g=I_{X}
$$
Similarly,
$$
(f\circ g)\circ (f\circ g)^{-1}=(f\circ g)\circ (g^{-1}\circ f^{-1})=f\circ(g\circ (g^{-1}\circ f^{-1}))=f\circ((g\circ g^{-1})\circ f^{-1})\\=f\circ (I_{Y}\circ f^{-1})=(f\circ I_{Y})\circ f^{-1}=f\circ f^{-1}=I_{Z}
$$

$(g^{-1}\circ f^{-1})\circ(f\circ g)=I_{X}$ and $(f\circ g)\circ (g^{-1}\circ f^{-1})=I_{Y}$ proves $f\circ g$ is invertible with $(f\circ g)^{-1}=g^{-1}\circ f^{-1}$.

Comment: Am I missing something? The first steps are using the equality you'd like to prove. Also, shouldn't the last line be $(f\circ g)\circ (g^{-1}\circ f^{-1})=I_{Z}$, and not $=I_{Y}$?

Answer (score 2):

Heres a hint: The jacket is put on after the shirt, but is taken off before
it.

Comment: This is essential what lhf said.

Answer (score 2):

let $(x,y) \in (f \circ g) ^{-1} $ 
$\Leftrightarrow (y,x) \in (f \circ g)$ 
$\Leftrightarrow \exists t((y,t) \in g  \land (t,x) \in f )$ 
$\Leftrightarrow \exists t((t,y) \in g^{-1} \land (x,t) \in f^{-1} )$
$\Leftrightarrow (x,y) \in g^{-1} \circ f^{-1}$

Answer (score -4):

This is straightforward. Take x in the domain of f. It goes to f(x) = y. And g takes y to z = g(y). Therefore $g^{-1}$ takes z to y and $f^{-1}$ takes y to x. Both sides of your equation takes $z$ to $x$.

Please try to think more before asking. This was not hard, was it? :)

Comment: I'm reading this book by myself, sometime it's seem very hard fro me to understand all of material without any suggestion. Anyway, I appreciate your help. =)

Comment: Sorry about the abrupt tone. I didn't mean to be rude. I have now softened it.

Comment: I apologize for my misunderstanding too.