# Find the inverse of g(x) = f(x) - 2

Tags: calculus

Can you help me understand how

$$g^{-1}(x) = f^{-1}(x + 2)$$

is the inverse of

$$g(x) = f(x) - 2$$

I cannot get my head around how the 2 ends up inside $f$ :/

thanks

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2349/how-to-prove-f-circ-g-1-g-1-circ-f-1/2426

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to complement Bill Dubuque's answer with trying to figure out *how* you might have come up with the formula, think about what $g(x)=f(x)-2$ is telling you to do: in order to compute $g(x)$, you first compute $f(x)$, and then you subtract $2$. The inverse of this should be something that "unravels" the process you just went to. So the first thing you need to unravel is the *last* thing you did when you computed $g(x)$, namely subtracting $2$. So the first thing you are going to do is add $2$ from whatever they give you. What did you did just prior to subtracting $2$ when you computed $g$? You computed $f$. So the next thing you need to do in the "unraveling" process is to undo the computation of $f$, which is achieved by computing $f^{-1}$.

In summary: to invert (unravel) the process of (i) first compute $f$, then (ii) subtract $2$; you will (I) first add $2$; then (II) compute $f^{-1}$. Symbolically: if you are given $x$ and you want to unravel, first you compute $x+2$, then you compute $f^{-1}$ of that. So if $g(x) = f(x)-2$, then $g^{-1}(x) = f^{-1}(x+2)$.

Answer (score 3):

It's simply $\rm\ g = h\: f\ \Rightarrow\ g^{-1} = (h\:f)^{-1} = f^{-1} h^{-1},\ \ h(x) = x-2\:.\ $

Or you can explicitly check that they're inverses, namely

$\rm\ g^{-1}(g(x)) = f^{-1}(g(x)+2) = f^{-1}(f(x)-2 + 2) = x$

$\rm\ g(g^{-1}(x)) = f(g^{-1}(x))-2 = f(f^{-1}(x+2))-2  = x$

Answer (score 1):

$$g(x) = f(x) - 2 = (h \circ f)(x)$$

where $h(x) = x - 2$ and of course $h^\circ(x) = x + 2$

Then the inverse $g^{\circ}(x) = (h \circ f)^{\circ}(x) = (f^{\circ}\circ h^{\circ})(x) = f^\circ(x + 2)$ by [the usual rules](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2349/how-to-prove-f-circ-g-1-g-1-circ-f-1/2426#2426).