# Show that $(g \circ f)^{-1}(C) = g^{-1}(f^{-1}(C)).$

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, inverse-function

Suppose that $f:S \rightarrow T$ and $g:T \rightarrow U$ are two functions and that $C \subseteq U.$ Show that $(g \circ f)^{-1}(C) = g^{-1}(f^{-1}(C)).$

Is the statement of this question is correct? or the correctness depends on whether the $(-1)$ represents the inverse function or the preimage (inverse image)?

Comment: It's not correct. It should be $(g \circ f)^{-1} = f^{-1} \circ g^{-1}$ for the preimage.

Comment: Note that $C$ is not even in $T$, so $f^{-1}(C)$ is not well-defined.

Comment: Related: [Prove that if $Z\subseteq Y$, then $(g\circ f)^{-1}(Z)=f^{-1}(g^{-1}(Z))$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/360333).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The statement doesn't make sense, since $C\subset U$ and $f$ is a map from $S$ into $T$. Therefore, $f^{-1}(C)$ is undefined.

However, it is true that$$(g\circ f)^{-1}(C)=f^{-1}\bigl(g^{-1}(C)\bigr).$$In fact\begin{align}x\in(g\circ f)^{-1}(C)&\iff g\bigl(f(x)\bigr)\in C\\&\iff f(x)\in g^{-1}(C)\\&\iff x\in f^{-1}\bigl(g^{-1}(C)\bigr).\end{align}

Comment: Do we need an extra assumption that $f,g$ are 1-1 and Onto as I saw this extra assumption found in Schaum Series of "general topology" on pg.25

Comment: No, we don't. Note that, here, $f^{-1}$ has nothing to do with inverse function. In fact, $f^{-1}(C)$ is the [inverse image](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_(mathematics)#Inverse_image) of $C$.