# $g(-x)$ is inverse of $f(-x)$?

Tags: real-analysis, functions

Something came to mind: if $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ is a bijection with inverse $g$. So can I say that $g(-x)$ is inverse of $f(-x)$? I think it is false but I have not been able to find a counterexample although visually the answer may seem affirmative since it is only a reflection with respect to the y-axis. Any idea or example? For example if defined $h_1(x)=f(-x)$ and $h_2(x)=g(-x)$ then $h_1(h_2(x))=f(-g(-x))¿=?id_{\mathbb R}$. If $f$ and $g$ were odd I think it would be trivial, but this is not the case.

Comment: Let $r(x)=-x$ be the negation. Observe that it is its own inverse, in other words $r^{-1}=r$. Anyway, the function $x\mapsto f(-x)$ is equal to the composition $f\circ r$. By the usual "inverse of the compositon rule"
$$(f\circ r)^{-1}=r^{-1}\circ f^{-1}=r\circ f^{-1}.$$
In your case $f^{-1}=g$, so the inverse of $f(-x)$ is $-g(x)$. You can also verfiy this easily enough.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Why are you answering in a comment?

Comment: @Arthur I have not had the time to search for a proper duplicate, yet. You may want to question my motives for posting an explanation in a comment. My practice here is to try and make the asker to see the light, and post a summary themself. That process is still in the works.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Wow how fast! It was much more than I expected, I just thought of counterexample $f(x)=x+2$ and $g(x)=x-2$, but your answer is absolute. Thank you

Comment: As I said in my comment to Arthur, Zaragosa. Unless a suitable duplicate target is found, you are welcome to post a verification of this process as an answer. That way you get more feedback on the details, and any unclear steps are discovered.

Comment: @Arthur, if you think I am violating some principle of the site, do start a meta discussion about it. It is always possible that I have overlooked something, and should revise my approach.

Comment: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2349/11619).

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Sorry for my little experience but I think you should post your answer, I don't see any weak points in your procedure and also no duplicate questions based on my question approach. Also, I think it's a very good solution.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to prove $(f \circ\ g) ^{-1} = g^{-1} \circ\ f^{-1}$? (inverse of composition)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2349/how-to-prove-f-circ-g-1-g-1-circ-f-1-inverse-of-compositio)

Comment: It doesn't do it directly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function that maps the number $x$ to $f(-x)$ is the composition of the negation $r:x\mapsto -x$ and $f$. By the general result on the inverse of a composition we have
$$(f\circ r)^{-1}=r^{-1}\circ f^{-1}.$$
Here $f^{-1}=g$ and $r^{-1}=r$, so the inverse you are looking for is the function
$$
r\circ g:x\mapsto -g(x).
$$